# Start Moving DBGrid Scrollbar After Come to the End of List (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, scroll, dbgrid

I have a DBGrid in my form that contains many items. Now I have tow the problems:
1- if items count in my DBGrid is less, I shouldn't be have vertical scrollbar.
2- when I click on each cell in DBGrid, Scrollbar start moving. while scrollbar should be start moving to down when I want to see (hidden or bottom) Items in the list. I couldn't find any options in DBGrid Properties for fix this solution.

**Picture of first problem: (show vertical scrollbar with less items)**

[image]

**Picture of Second problem: (Moving Scrollbar after click on DBGrid cells)**

In this picture, scrollbar should be start moving down when I want to show Item 25

[image]

Comment: For the first issue, the scrollbar will be visible; it is correctly disabled when there are not enough rows to need to scroll. There is no option to turn that off, because the behavior is exactly as designed.  For the second, your expectation is wrong. That's not the way scrollbars work. They move proportional to the amount of data that is available - it has nothing to do with the visible amount of rows. Delphi offers the choice to not provide proportional scrollbars, but that means that the thumb shows either the top, middle or bottom, with nothing in between.

Comment: I Fixed first issue. But for second issue, is there a way to control Scrollbar manually with code?

Comment: Not the one that is part of the DBGrid, because its behavior is built into that component. I don't know why you want to *fix* something that works exactly as it should, and exactly the way the Windows scrollbar is designed to work (which is what all users of your app will expect as well).

Comment: I captured a video and show Scrollbar in C# and Delphi. Now you can now why I say scrollbar in delphi does not work properly. [Compare C# and Delphi Scrollbar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAVldv17iz8)

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what's happening. When you click on a row in the DBGrid, it moves the table's record pointer to the row where you clicked. This moves the scrollbar, because you're no longer at the beginning of the table. The scrollbar position is based on the current position of the record pointer in relation to the total number of records are in the table. The scrollbar's thumb size is also adjusted based on the total number of records. In the second image you posted, I'd guess you have about 50 rows in the table, and being on the 10th row means you're 20% of the way

Comment: (continued) from the beginning of the data, which means that the scrollbar is in exactly the position it should be in. This means that the scrollbar is working *exactly as designed*, which means there is no issue here. Comparing C# and Delphi is meaningless, because a) they're not using the same control; and b) they may not be looking at the same exact data in the same exact way. Delphi's DBGrid has been around since Delphi 1, and has consistently worked the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Best Solution for fix these issues is use NextDBGrid6 component from [bergsoft](http://www.bergsoft.net/en-us/product/next-grid).